# Tough Sql Query problem involving family relationsships

Tags: t-sql, crystal-reports

i have a many to many table relationship that involves 2 logical tables.

Record table that joins to a relation table on primaryID
Second instance of record table that joins to the relation table on ReciprocalID

The purpose of this is to show family relations within the database. Each primary Record table has one or more rows in the relationtable that shows everyother family relationship this person has in the database.

I have been tasked with trying to make a contact list that involves displaying the names of each of the children that attend this school along with their parents and contact information.

I have gotten to a point where I am able to show the children under each parent, but now I have to find a way to merge these together.

Since I have no control over the design of this database(its Education Edge 7) I have made a separate database that holds my queries and views for my reports. The school I am doing this work for only has access to CR 8.5.

Right now I have my top group in CR as the lastname of the recordstable, my second group is on the fullname of the recordstable. I have a subreport that pulls in all the child records.

I have used a case when statement in my primary view(the one described above) to convert 'daughter' and 'son' to child and 'mother' or 'father' to parent.

hopefully this hasnt rambled too much. If you need anymore information just ask.

```
SELECT     dbo.vwEA7RelationshipsTableView.PRIMARYID,
             dbo.vwEA7RecordsTableView.LASTNAME AS PRIMARYLASTNAME,
            dbo.vwEA7RecordsTableView.FIRSTNAME AS PRIMARYFIRSTNAME,
             dbo.vwEA7RecordsTableView.NAMEFORDISPLAY AS PRIMARYNAME,
             CASE dbo.vwEA7RelationshipsTableView.PRIMARYDESC 
                WHEN 'Father' THEN 'Parent' 
                WHEN 'Mother' THEN 'Parent' 
                WHEN 'Son' THEN 'Child'
                 WHEN'Daughter' THEN 'Child'
                 ELSE dbo.vwEA7RelationshipsTableView.PRIMARYDESC 
                END AS PRIMARYDESC,
            dbo.vwEA7RelationshipsTableView.RELATIONID,
            vwEA7RecordsTableView_1.LASTNAME AS RELATIONLASTNAME,
            vwEA7RecordsTableView_1.NAMEFORDISPLAY AS RELATIONNAME,
             dbo.vwEA7RelationshipsTableView.RELATIONDESC
FROM         dbo.vwEA7RelationshipsTableView INNER JOIN
                      dbo.vwEA7RecordsTableView ON
                         dbo.vwEA7RelationshipsTableView.PRIMARYID = dbo.vwEA7RecordsTableView.ID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.vwEA7RecordsTableView AS vwEA7RecordsTableView_1 ON
                         dbo.vwEA7RelationshipsTableView.RELATIONID = vwEA7RecordsTableView_1.ID
```

TableViews are really just recreation of the primary tables from the main database.

Comment: "I have gotten to a point where I am able to show the children under each parent, but now I have to find a way to merge these together" - can you describe what you mean by this?

Comment: there are several descriptions available for each record in the Relations Table. Each Record has one or more records in the Relationtable that tells the relation of the primary id to the relation id. so:

1  Jane doe Mother 23 John Doe jr Son
1  Jane Doe Mother 24 Jane Doe Jr Daughter
1  Jane Doe Wife   25 John Doe Husband
25 John Doe Husband 1 Jane doe Wife
25 John Doe Father 23 John Doe Jr Son

Thats the original data. I took and made Father Mother = Parent and Daughter Son = Child

Comment: I need to be able to find a way to show a record as such:

Doe, Jane Jr
Doe, John Jr
Mr And Mrs John Doe   Jane
ADDRESS 
City State Zip.

right now my main problem is how to manipulate my records in order to do this in Crystal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. My sql code was good, it was a matter of formatting my internal paramaters for Crystal as well as some creative grouping.

Comment: Don't forget that you can mark this as the correct answer if you figured it out. :)

Comment: yep, i tried it that day, but it told me I had to wait for 2 days...doing it now...